# Wordpress Multisite Cron Issue

Tags: multisite, wp-cron, cron

I'm having some very weird cron issues.
I was looking to run cron on a multisite subfolder install.
And I user Debug Bar Cron plugin to see my cron jobs.

I can see that the cron jobs are running fine on the main site.
But on the subdomain none of the scheduled crons are running.
I've tried close to everything. I've even asked the host they keep saying it's a plugin conflict but i've tried it with all plugins deactivated as well as changing the themes.

Any ideas?

Comment: You might be better off disabling standard WP cron (which relies on a HTTP hit to trigger) and setting up a system cron job [(source)](https://tigr.net/3203/2014/09/13/getting-wordpress-cron-work-in-multisite-environment/)

Comment: Actually i'm hosting it on WP Engine, if you're familiar with them. 
They've enable alternative cron which i don't know is what.
And when i do a http://example.com/wp-cron.php?doing_cron the cron jobs run but they aren't when left to run on their own.

Like i said works without a hitch on the main site, the subfolder subdomain is my problem

Comment: If you're with WP Engine, I'm surprised they haven't been more helpful...